# How to capture TextArea text changed event in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using QR Code Reader JavaScript.
This JavaScript captures image using camera, tries to decode QR Code and set the decoded text to TextArea as output.

This is working well.

But when text set to TextArea I need to capture event so I can do further processing.

I have tried different combinations with available solutions as follows:

1st

```
$('.barcodeInput').change(function(){
    debugger;
    alert("changed");
});
```

2nd

```
$('body').delegate('.barcodeInput', 'keyup change', function(){
    alert("changed");
});
```

3rd

```
$('.barcodeInput').bind('input propertychange', function () {
    debugger;
    alert("changed");
});
```

I have defined all these in and out side of `document.ready(function(){ // code here});`

But still it is not wroking.

My QR Code decoding JavaScript set text to TextArea after successful decoding.

I can trigger event manually form that JavaScript but that will be patch work.

I want permanent solution for problem like these.

Thanks is advance

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual problem is, but `change` only fires when the element loses focus. Try using `input` instead.

Comment: How about your jquery version? why don't you try with `.on()` listener?

Comment: Does your plugin fires `trigger('change')` event when changing Textarea value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could attach the event using `change()` or `.on()`, like :

```
$('.barcodeInput').change(function(){
    alert("changed");
});
//Or
$('.barcodeInput').on('change', function(){
    alert("changed");
});
```

And you could invoke the event when you change the text :

```
textarea.val('new val').change();
//Or
textarea.val('new val').trigger('change');
```

**NOTE :** `bind` and `delegate` are deprecated.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.barcodeInput').on('change', function(){
    alert("changed");
});

$('.barcodeInput').val('new val').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='barcodeInput'></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but .change() or .trigger(change) both are not working in my case.   I have QRCode reading JavaScript separate so may be it is not working.

Comment: Are you using any library ?

Comment: Sorry, Its working fine, It was not working due to cached JavaScript.  I cleared all data of browser and retry. now its working fine.. Thanks a lot.